# How to get Angular 2 response headers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular

I am using Angular 2 to request JSON from my Rails API server. My server is set to respond with a header `X-Total-Count: 10`. My server is successfully sending those headers:

[image: Server Response]

But when I try to `console.log(res.headers)` the http response, I only receive a `_headersMap` with `Content-Type` and `Cache-Control`:

[image]

Here is my Rack::Cors config:

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, "Rack::Cors" do
    allow do
        origins '*'
        resource '*', headers: :any, methods: [:get, :post, :options, :patch, :delete], expose: ['X-Total-Count']
    end
end
```

And the way I'm setting the headers in the controller:

```
  def index
    ...
    @posts = ...

    response.headers['X-Total-Count'] = '10'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'X-Total-Count'

    render json: @posts
  end
```

How can I ensure that the `X-Total-Count` is appears in the `_headersMap`? Or, how can I access the `X-Total-Count` value response?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the issue. Even though I was exposing the header through the `Rack::Cors` configuration, it didn't work until I made changes to [fix this deprecation](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors/issues/92). Now, the following configuration, set in `config/initializers/cors.rb`, properly exposes the headers:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*',
    headers: :any,
    methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head],
    expose: ['X-Total-Count']
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this bug posted in alpha](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5237#issuecomment-156059284) this is caused by your browser considering certain headers "unsafe" and rejecting their access.  The fix in that thread was to add a header to your server response:

```
access-control-expose-headers: x-total-count
```

Comment: No luck. I'm adding my Rack Cors config above. The `X-Total-Count` has been exposed, but it's still not working.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of CORS. You're only be able to see the header in the map only if it's enabled by CORS.

Your server needs to return the following in headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Total-Count
```

Comment: Still no luck. I've posted the `Rack::Cors` config that I currently have. Also, wouldn't it need to be `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Total-Count`? I gave both version a shot.

Comment: Is your request a simple one or à preflighted one?